# WSDL generated service reference returning null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, wsdl, service-reference

Im have some issues with a service reference to an external source (added it using the supplied wsdl in Visual Studio 2015).

The situation is that the request i run seems to reach the server fine. I also seems to get a response of the expected xml format (added TextWriterTraceListener). But the OutType class i get back in the code (in this case the GetBankCertificateOutType) is always null.

The console application ive built to illustrate is very simple, utilizing the public test account. It looks as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //instantiates client from the service reference
            var client = new PkiServicePortTypeClient();

            var time = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Random r = new Random();
            string reqId = r.Next(100, 999).ToString();

            var outType = client.GetBankCertificate(*full params on github*);

            //This line will throw nullexception since outType is always null
            //BUT a valid response is actually received (although returning aa application statusCode that represents error at this stage)
            var response = outType.GetBankCertificateResponse;
        }
```

Ive tried to locate the problem but have been unsuccessful sofar. So wanted to see if someone has some good tip on how to debug this or perhaps has a solution.

I built a complete, minimal, console sample project (including the source wsdl) to illustrtate the issue which is located [here](https://github.com/baseless/ServiceReferenceSample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've downloaded and inspected your solution, and I found this in trace.log

```
GetBankCertificateRequest at tribute {http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}id  had invalid value '360817' of type '{http://www .w3.org/2001/XML Schema}ID'
```

After I played with `id` value of `GetBankCertificateRequest` I got back the right value (instead of null).

```
var outType = client.GetBankCertificate(new GetBankCertificateInType {
            RequestHeader = new RequestHeaderType {
                SenderId = "360817",
                CustomerId = "360817",
                RequestId = reqId,
                Environment = EnvironmentType.test,
                EnvironmentSpecified = true,
                InterfaceVersion = "1",
                Timestamp = time
            },
            GetBankCertificateRequest = new GetBankCertificateRequest {
                BankRootCertificateSerialNo = "1111110002",
                //id = "",
                RequestId = reqId,
                Timestamp = time
            }
        });
```

There is no description for this property according to documentation (`PKI service description v2.3.pdf`) except some xml type annotation (`xml:id`). The concrete schema description is missing.

Comment: Your absolutely right, and it worked fine. I saw that message but interpreted is as a result of the server rejecting it, not something that would cause deserialization issues. Thanks a lot for that, stared me right in the face while i was trying to debug the service reference :).